# EF Designer from database with DataAnnotations

Tags: c#

Is there any way possible to generate the database object in model.edmx with DataAnnotations(like Required, StringLength)?

Answer (score 0):

When you use database first approach with EF all your classes are generated as `partial` classes. Which means you can spilt the definition over two or more source files. **If you make changes to the generate class it will be overwritten**.

Let's say you have a partial class of User generated by EF as

```
public partial class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Telphone { get; set; }
}
```

Now to use `DataAnnotations` on the properties of `User` you would create a new source file with the same name in the same namespace and make use of `MetadataType` attribute as:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public partial class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Telphone { get; set; }
}

public class UserMetaData
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Telephone number")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I've used `MetadataType` attribute in the second example which specifies the metadata class to associate with a data model class.

Comment: Is this possible go generate it with the t4 template?

Comment: @AggieR you can also have a look at **[this](https://t4metadatatemplate.codeplex.com/)** project on codeplex for t4 template